# Delete Data Form Firebase Table Based On Value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to Delete data who has Value is "Screen2"

```
{
 "mobilereg" : {
    "1245639856" : {
      "screen" : "Screen2"
    },
    "1254789632" : {
      "screen" : "Screen2"
    },
    "1452369852" : {
      "screen" : "Screen2"
    },
    "2589632587" : {
      "screen" : "Screen2"
    }
  }
}
```

Delte those numbers whose Screen value is "Screen2":

[image: Delte those numbers whose Screen value is "Screen2"]

Answer (score 0):

For deleting value in firebase you can use `remove()` function on the firebase reference to `mobilereg` node where child value is `Screen2`.

```
let mobileregRef = firebase.database().ref().child("mobilereg")
mobileregRef
  .once('value', s => {
    if (s.exists()) {
      // map through objects returned from mobileregRef and map through the objects
      Object.keys(s.val()).map(k => {
          // deleting the node which contains `Screen2` as value
          if(s.val()[k]=="Screen2"){
            s.ref.remove()
          }
      })
    }
})
```